# Prove that $27195^8-10887^8+10152^8$ is divisible by $26460$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

so I was assigned a divisibility question for homework.

> Prove that $27195^8-10887^8+10152^8$ is divisible by $26460$.

Am I supposed to use mods?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: First thing to do: What is the prime decomposition of $26460$?

Comment: Second thing to do is to subtract 26460 from  27195.

Comment: Okay, I have already done that. It is 2^2*3*5*431

Comment: $2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 431 = 28560$.  The actual factorization
is more helpful :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8$ is divisible by 26460, then it should be divisible also by $49, 4, 9$ and $5$, because: $26460 = 49 \cdot 4 \cdot 27 \cdot 5$

Now we have:

$$27195 \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \implies 27195^8 \equiv 3^8 \equiv 9^4 \equiv 1^4 \equiv 1\pmod 4$$

$$10887 \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \implies 10887^8 \equiv 3^8 \equiv 9^4 \equiv 1^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$$

$$10512 \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \implies 10512^8 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$

Now add all this congruence relation adn you'll end up with:

$$27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8 \equiv 1 - 1 + 0 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$$

Which means $27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8$ is divisible by 4. Now we continue:

$$27195 \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \implies 27195^8 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$
$$10887 \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \implies 10887^8 \equiv 2^8 \equiv 4^4 \equiv (-1)^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
$$10512 \equiv 2 \pmod 5 \implies 10152^8 \equiv 2^8 \equiv 4^4 \equiv (-1)^4 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$

Again add all congruence relation:

$$27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8 \equiv 0 - 1 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

We proved that $$27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8$ is divisible by 5. Two more to go.

$$27195 \equiv 6 \pmod {27} \implies 27195^8 \equiv 6^8 \equiv 36^4 \equiv 9^4 \equiv 81^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$$
$$10887 \equiv 6 \pmod {27} \implies 10887^8 \equiv 6^8 \equiv 36^4 \equiv 9^4 \equiv 81^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$$
$$10152 \equiv 0 \pmod {27} \implies 10152^8 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$$

Now add them all:

$$27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8 \equiv 0 - 0 + 0 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$$

Now we need to show it's divisible by 49.

$$27195 \equiv 0 \pmod {49} \implies 27195^8 \equiv 0 \pmod {49}$$
$$10887 \equiv 9 \pmod {49} \implies 10887^8 \equiv 9^8 \equiv 81^4 \equiv (-17)^4 \equiv 289^2 \equiv (-5)^2 \equiv 25 \pmod {49}$$
$$10152 \equiv 9 \pmod {49} \implies 10152^8 \equiv 9^8 \equiv 81^4 \equiv (-17)^4 \equiv 289^2 \equiv (-5)^2 \equiv 25 \pmod {49}$$

Now we add them all:

$$27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8 \equiv 0 - 25 + 25 \equiv 0 \pmod {49}$$

We obtained that:

$$27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8 \equiv 0 \pmod {4}$$
$$27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8 \equiv 0 \pmod {5}$$
$$27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$$
$$27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8 \equiv 0 \pmod {49}$$

If we "glue" this together we'll end up with:

$$27195^8 - 10887^8 + 10152^8 \equiv 0 \pmod {26460}$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Nice, but 26460 = 4 * 27 * 5 * 49.

Comment: Okay, but since each term is divisible by 3, it doesn't really matter. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've missed one 3. I'll edit the answer.